# Leading Zeroes Getting Trimmed while loading data into excel using unix

Tags: database, unix, export-to-excel

Leading Zeroes Getting Trimmed while loading data into excel using unix . My platform is MAC. Is there any way we can handle it in Unix without any manual effort.

Thanks

Comment: Are you opening an Excel file using Open Office in Linux?

Comment: Nopes. Im just redirecting tab separated data in the excel file.

Answer (score 1):

The leading zeroes are removed because as strings containing digits only are converted into numbers. Nothing stops you from changing the format the numbers to show leading zeroes or convert the column to text.

Comment: that would be a manual effort, i was hoping to avoid the manual effort if possible.

Comment: just changed the extension to .xlsx and loaded directly thru a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Convert numbers into strings with something like

```
cat inputfile | while read line
   quoteLine=$(echo ${line}|sed 's/,/","/g')
   # do not forget first and last quote, some ugly backslashes here
   echo "\"${quoteLine}\""
done > outputfile.csv
```

In your case (TAB-separated), you can replace the first `,` in the sed command by a TAB. Difficult to see when you copy-paste, so you can do it after copying.